# Button: Create one object, then redirect to create another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

railsnoobquestion: I am trying to develop a feature where a user can save an object in rails and is then forwarded to the form again, to create another object.

I could think of two options:
-Create a fully new route
-Add data to the restaurant post object, check for that data in the controller?

Has anyone built a similar feature?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a hidden form field with another submit button:

```
%input#create_another{:name => "create_another", :type => "hidden", :value => 0 }
%a.btn.btn-info#submit_another
```

Then use javascript to submit the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit_another").click(function() {
    $('#create_another').attr('value','1');
    console.log($('#create_another').attr('value'));
    $(".formtastic").submit();
    return true;
  });
});
```

Inside the respective controller, in my case, category controller:

```
if params[:create_another].nil?
  @create_another = false
else
  @create_another = (params[:create_another] == "1")
end
respond_to do |format|
  if @category.save
    if @create_another
      format.html { redirect_to new_restaurant_category_path(@restaurant), notice: I18n.t(:entry_successfully_created, :name => I18n.t(:category_singular)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a standard create action for the posts resource.

```
def create
  @post = Post.new params[:post]

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

All you would need to do is change the redirect from `@post` to `new_post_path`.

`redirect_to new_post_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'`

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I will post my solution, similar to yours.